# Use the ajax values inside the functions.

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

```
<?php
  echo $getname;//value from ajax
 function mail_send()
   {
    $to      = "sample@gmail.com";
    $subject = "admin reference";
    $message ="hai <b> $getname </b>";//here i cant get the name from ajax
   }

 ?>
```

Actually i need to know how to use the ajax values inside the php function.When i normally **echo $getname;** i can view the output.But when i try to get the same value inside a function i can't.

Tell me how to fix it!!

Comment: `"hai <b> $getname </b>"` is valid because double quotes let `$getname` be parsed as a variable, so that's not the issue.
THe issue is probably related to the scope of the variable.

Comment: Ya thats why i'm asking,how to solve it ji :)

Comment: Can you show me what part of the code is actually making a call/invoking mail_send() ?

Comment: It would help a lot to have the rest of the code, as I suspect you posted just a fragment.

Comment: if($time_difference > 20){$email=mail_send();}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass the variable as a parameter to the function:

```
function mail_send($getname)
{
    $to      = "sample@gmail.com";
    $subject = "admin reference";
    $message ="hai <b> $getname </b>";//here i cant get the name from ajax
}
```

When you use the function, you should write:

```
mail_send($getname);
```

This has nothing to do with AJAX, it's just normal variable scoping in PHP. Variables created outside a function are not visible inside the function unless you use the `global` declaration. But arguments are usually better because it allows the function to be used from different parts of the code with different variables.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add the `global` keyword since you're not in the same scope.
Something like :

```
<?php
 function mail_send()
   {
    global $getname;
    $to      = "sample@gmail.com";
    $subject = "admin reference";
    $message ="hai <b> $getname </b>";//here i cant get the name from ajax
   }

 ?>
```

Comment: Though the answer isn't wrong, but isn't using `global` discouraged?

Comment: Possibly yes. I'm not really into PHP good practices, the important thing is to understand the scopes. The classic "multi-language" option would be to add the value as a parameter to the function.

Comment: @Kiruthiga As using `global` seems discouraged, you may want to try Barmar proposition.